# AutoRest parameters in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, swagger, autorest

When using AutoRest in Visual Studio 2015 (Right click project -> Add -> REST API Client), where are the parameters that are passed to autorest.exe?

How can I set or change any flags being passed in by Visual Studio?

Is there a default settings file somewhere?

When generating code (C#) in a library project, AutoRest is only generating the async methods and not the sync methods (which I want). I suspect this has something to do with the parameters being passed by Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi, you can find autorest.exe and run it from command prompt with -? to see if there is any information that migt help. Btw. How are your "get" methods generated? I for instance have domain types used for Get "all" request, but `object` type used for Get "by id" (and so - my Get "all" request works properly, bet Get "by id" is not working - if I manually change generated code to use my specific type instead of `object` then my request Get "by id" is working properly. Is your code for Get "by id" generated same way?

Comment: P.S. SwaggerConfig.cs provides some configuration options (uncomment what's necessary)

Comment: do you have the Swagger file that produces above behavior? If so, I can assist you further. :-)

Comment: Irrespective of my current issue, do you know where the default settings are for AutoRest when used in Visual Studio? Or if we can change them. This is just one issue that I'm having.